# Restore Slick Greeter in Budgie?

Tags: login, lightdm, budgie

I am using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.4

I was fiddling with the Login Window and lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings apps in an attempt to change the background in lightdm. However a side-effect appears to be that I have lost the slick greeter with the nice transparent login box.

Does anybody have any idea how to get it back?

Comment: The greeter is called `slick-greeter" and can be reset with the linked Q&A.  BTW the Menu - Login Window is used in Ubuntu Budgie to change the background picture.

Comment: You can change the background picture anyway in Nemo, so seems a bit pointless. Login Window has many functions. Your link does not actually answer the question for Budgie.